# 'API First' security best-practices

Tags: symfony, csrf, restful-architecture

I'm developing an API for a project I'm involved in. The API will be consumed by an Android app, an iOS app, and a desktop website. Almost all of the API is accessible only to registered users. The API allows authentication via WSSE which is great for the mobile apps, but not so great for the website. However, I'm using Symfony2 to develop the API, and I have configured it to allow access to the API by both WSSE and/or session/cookie authentication (multiple firewalls with common security context, if you're interested).

With an API-first approach like this, I'm concerned about things being abused. Take my signup method for example. I only want it to be used by the apps or the website. However, there's nothing to stop someone writing a simple script to hammer the API with bogus signups. Then there's the concern about CSRF. Because the API is can be accessed by a logged in user, then there's a risk that this can be exploited.

I don't want the API to be public, but I don't know if this is possible given that it will be used by the website. Is there anything I can do remove (or reduce) the risks and the vulnerability exposure?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

For the signup brut force problem you could enable a "rate limit" for your API calls.

This [blog post](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/05/28/throttle-your-api-calls-ratelimitbundle/) introduces this concept and how to use it in a Symfony2 application thanks to the [RateLimitBundle](https://github.com/jaytaph/RateLimitBundle).